# How to update Sencha Touch List when user scrolls to end of list

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an application where I have around 1000 records to be displayed  in sencha list from localstore. If i try to populate all the data at one shot then it takes long time to refresh the list (around 1 minute).

Now I want to load list with initial 20 records and then it should load next 20 as user scroll down. How to capture the event when user scrolls to end of list?

Comment: you have to use listpaging plugin for it.

Comment: @NareshTank. Cant we find the event when user reaches to end of the list while scrolling?

Comment: check this document http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.ListPaging

Comment: @NareshTank. Thanks for your reply. I believe that will serve my purpose. But the example in Sencha docs is more confusing.  can you help me to get a working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is excerpt from [Secncha Doc site](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-plugins)

```
Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', {
    config: {
        plugins: [
            {
                xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
                pullRefreshText: 'Pull to refresh...'
            },
            {
                xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
                autoPaging: true
            }
        ],

        itemTpl: '<div class="item">{title}</div>',
        store: 'Items'
    }
});
```

From me I'm adding instead of xclass: '' you could also use xtype: 'listpaging'. It also works...

Cheers, Oleg

PS. if it is not still clear paste your code snippets here...

Answer (score 0):

To add to oleg sencha does not paginate ie your pagination logic must be in the server side the plugin only increments the page parameter by 1 which can be configured in the pageParam config in the ajaxProxy of the store